Return a value when its ID is greater than or equal to Column C and less than or equal to Column D
I have a report where the data is displayed as

In a different report I have a list of IDs that I match with the list in the original report.
Some IDs that I'm trying to get a name for are in-between the values displayed such as 84286.
Ive tried to use the below formula to get a result but its not returning the correct values.
=INDEX('[DID Codes.xlsx]DID Codes'!$E:$E, MATCH(1, (Y2 >= '[DID Codes.xlsx]DID Codes'!$C:$C) * (Y2 <= '[DID Codes.xlsx]DID Codes'!$D:$D), 0))
Any assistance will be greatly apricated

If you are a user of Microsoft-365 then use FILTER() function.

Could you please elaborate? im not sure how that would help me


Formula to get names in cell B8 and drag down:
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$4;SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$4<=A8)*--($B$2:$B$4>=A8)*ROW($C$2:$C$4)));"Not found") 

